# Why do I need the inverse of the bind pose matrix to calculate animations?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to implement animations in OpenGL but I don‘t really understand the inverse bind pose matrix. As far as I understand it, this matrix is used to ‚revert‘ any previous deformations applied to my vertices. But why would I even need that? Why can‘t I just pass the positions of my vertices that I loaded from the file to the GPU and apply the bone‘s rotation ans translation without any additional calculation? The GPU won‘t modify the vertex positions on the client side so I don‘t think I would have to revert any previous transformation, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mesh vertices are defined in object space. To apply bone transformation correctly vertex must be in bone local space. So, a pose is applied in two steps:

1. Transform vertex from object space to bone space (inverse bind pose matrix)
2. Transform vertex from bone space to "animation" space (bone matrix from animation)

Also, you can't pre-transform vertex to bone space 'cos (usually) vertex affected by more than one bone. (Thanks to [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas))

Comment: You should probably also mention that the weighted vertices are meant to be animated in multiple spaces (according to their weights), so the vertex cannot just be in bone-local space, since it would have multiple bone-local spaces to be in.

Comment: Thank you guys! So do I just calculate `AnimationMatrix * BindPoseInvMatrix * vertex` for every bone that affects the vertex?

Comment: @NicolaCrivellin YWa, but you should premultiply `AnimationMatrix * BindPoseInvMatrix` to one matrix, so you'll have only one matrix*vertex multiplication per vertex

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. But Lets say my Animation only contains identity matrices (i.e. no animation). wouldn't that mean my models would become a mess, since it effectively would apply the inverse bind pose only?

Comment: To get skinning done you must have bone transformation. Your animation might have only identity matrices, but bone transformations for skinning can't (unless they all located in the same 0,0,0 point and has the same rotation and scale).